# Data constructors without breaking the open/closed principle

Tags: haskell, constructor, open-closed-principle

I have a data constructor like this

```
class FooClass a where
    foo :: a -> b

class BarClass a where
    bar :: a -> b

data FooBar = Foo :: FooClass a => a -> IO ()
            | Bar :: BarClass a => a -> IO ()
```

So that I can use pattern matching:

```
foobar :: FooBar -> a -> IO ()
foobar (Foo f) x = f (foo x)
foobar (Bar f) x = f (bar x)
```

However, this breaks the open/closed principle.
I'd like to be able to extend `FooBar` with additional methods based on other classes.

How would I implement this in Haskell?

Comment: This code doesn't compile - what are you trying to do? I don't see how you can implement `foo` or `bar` with those types.

Comment: How does the "open-closed" principle apply in a non-OO language? I'm not sure your principle makes sense in the context of Haskell's type system.

Comment: There only is exactly one "meaningful" instance for both these classes: [`instance Foo Void where foo = absurd`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/void-0.6.1/docs/Data-Void.html). For any other instance you could only set `foo = const undefined`. I suspect you actually mean `foo :: a -> B` for some fixed type `B`.... but then why don't you just store plain `B` values everywhere, apply `foo` before storing?

Comment: @DonStewart OCP is not specific to OO languages. It says that extending your software, such that old code can use new code, should not require modifications to old code. In OO this is achieved by subclassing, in FP... right, by using higher order functions.

Comment: Sounds very similar to "[The Expression Problem](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/expression/expression.txt)" in FP/types. If the user is asking for a solution to the expression problem, in a statically typed setting, then that is an interesting question. Though perhaps "old and new" functions are less interesting than "old types and new types"

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, this code is flawed in ways that obscure your question. It's also probably dangerous to try to think too hard about how OO principles translate to FP. They have a place, because much of OO is embedded in FP naturally, but it's much better to learn FP directly first and then observe the laws later as certain special cases.

In particular, we can talk about how greater refinement of types is a form of extension. For instance, comparing the types like

```
(Num a)         => a -> IO ()
(Num a, Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

we can talk about how the second function takes in a set of types which is a natural subtype of the inputs to the first function. In particular, the set of possible types that can be input to the second function is a refinement of the inputs to the first. As users of these functions, there are fewer valid ways to use the second function. As implementers of these functions, there are more valid ways to implement the second function. In fact, we know the following

1. All values which are valid inputs to the second function are also valid inputs to the first
2. All functions which are correctly typed by the first signature are also correctly typed by the second.

This duality between giving and taking is explored in the study of [Game semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_semantics). The idea of "open for extension" plays out trivially in that we can always decide to ask for a more refined type, but it's almost completely uninteresting since that's just obvious in how refined types are used.

---

So what about ADTs (`data` declarations) directly? Are then Open/Closed? [Mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29)—ADTs aren't objects, so the rule does not apply directly.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to doing your example in Haskell is to use functions instead of classes:

```
-- FooBar is like a base class
-- with methods foo and bar.
-- I've interpreted your example liberally
-- for purposes of illustration.
-- In particular, FooBar has two methods -
-- foo and bar - with different signatures.
data FooBar = FooBar {
  foo :: IO (),
  bar :: Int -> Int
}

-- Use functions for classes, like in Javascript.
-- This doesn't mean Haskell is untyped, it just means classes are not types.
-- Classes are really functions that make objects.
fooClass :: Int -> FooBar
fooClass n = FooBar {
    foo = putStrLn ("Foo " ++ show n)
    bar = \n -> n+1
}

barClass :: FooBar
barClass = FooBar {
    foo = putStrLn "Bar ",
    bar = \n -> n * 2
}

-- Now we can define a function that uses FooBar and it doesn't matter
-- if the FooBar we pass in came from fooClass, barClass or something else,
-- bazClass, say.
foobar (FooBar foo bar) = do
    -- invoke foo
    foo
    -- use bar
    print (bar 7)
```

Here `FooBar` is 'open for extension' because we can create as many `FooBar` values as we like with different behaviours.

To 'extend' `FooBar` with another field, `baz`, without changing `FooBar`, `fooClass` or `barClass`, we need to declare a `FooBarBaz` type that includes a `FooBar`. We can still use our `foobar` function, we just have to first extract the `FooBar` from the `FooBarBaz` first.

So far, I've been keeping close to OOP. This is because Bertrand Meyer worded the open closed principle to require OOP or something very like it:

> software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open
>   for extension, but closed for modification

In particular, the word "extension" is traditionally interpreted as meaning "subclassing". If you're prepared to interpret the principle as merely "having extension points", then any function that takes another function as parameter is "open for extension". This is so common in functional programming that it's not considered a principle. The "parameterisation principle" just doesn't sound the same.